# How can I add a button that adds the answer to the inputs, next to the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code written here but there is something I want to add to it that I would like help with, and not being a master coder I don't know what to do.

Here is my code so far

```js
function calculate() {
  var A = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var B = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var C = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var D = document.getElementById("d").value;

  var ans = ((A * B) - (C * D)) / (B - C);
  alert(ans);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #05537b;
}

.thisTable td {
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left
}

.box {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
}

.button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  width: 25px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.answer {
  padding-left: 10px
}

.answer b {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.how {
  color: #555;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 2px 4px
}

.how b {
  color: #D00;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div style="width:1000px; background-color:#FFF; padding:10px 20px; text-align:center; -moz-border-radius:10px">
    <div style="font-size:30px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:20px; padding-top:8px">Average Damage Calculator</div>
    <div class=container>
      <h3>Calculate Target Average</h3>
      <table class=thisTable>
        <tr>
          <td>Type in your target average damage <input type='number' id='a' /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Type the amount of battles you want to achieve it by <input type='number' id='b' /></td>
          <tr>
            <td>Type in your current number of battles <input type='number' id='c' /></td>
            <tr>
              <td>Type in your current average damage <input type='number' id='d' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <button onClick='calculate()'>calculate</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I have it, so that when the user types in the information and clicks the "calculate" button, the answer pops up in like a small window. But I don't want that to happen. What I want to happen instead, is that, when you click the "calculate" button, the answer (a number) will appear right below, or next to the button instead of popping up on the screen. I would also like to refine the answer from being so specific, and only have it round the thousandth decimal.

Comment: I'm only getting answers like `175`. What would be a typical input giving an answer with decimals?

Comment: @thijs I should have added backstory maybe. The damage inputs would be in the low thousands (2450 or 3300) and the battles would be in the hundreds (350, 678) it's for a video game :)

Comment: So, target damage 3300, achieve in 100 battles, current battles 350 and current damage 2800. Something like this (I'm still getting integer results).

Comment: In order (top to bottom) what I'm putting in it: 2700,500,261,2629

The answer Is around 2777

Answer (score 1):

I've added a `span` next to the `button`. Instead of showing an alert after calculating a score, the answer is placed in the `span`.

```js
function calculate(){
  // The value property returns a string, use parseInt to convert it to an integer.
  var targetAvgDamage = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value, 10),
      numberOfBattles = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value, 10),
      battlesFought = parseInt(document.getElementById("c").value, 10),
      currentAvgDamage = parseInt(document.getElementById("d").value, 10);

  var answer = ((targetAvgDamage * numberOfBattles) - (battlesFought * currentAvgDamage)) / (numberOfBattles - battlesFought);
  
  // Get the element from the DOM to place the answer in.
  var answerCell = document.getElementById('answer-cell');
  // Set the text content of the element.
  answerCell.textContent = 'The answer is: ' + Math.ceil(answer);
}

var
  // Get the button element from the DOM.
  calculateTrigger = document.getElementById('calculate-btn');
// Attach an event handler for the visitor clicks on the button.
calculateTrigger.addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

```css
* { font-family:arial; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin:40px; background-color:#05537b; }
.thisTable td { line-height:36px; font-size:14px; }
.container { background-color:#EEE; padding:5px 15px 15px 15px; border:1px solid #CCC; margin-bottom:25px; width:100%; text-align:left }
.box { background-color:#FFF; border:1px solid #CCC; width:40px; margin:0px 4px; }
.button { margin-left:10px; background-color:#333; border:1px solid #CCC; width:25px; color:#FFF; font-weight:bold; }
.answer { padding-left:10px }
.answer b { text-decoration:underline }
.how { color:#555; margin-left:15px; font-size:13px; background-color:#FFF; padding:2px 4px }
.how b { color:#D00; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none }
```

```html
<div style="width:1000px; background-color:#FFF; padding:10px 20px; text-align:center; -moz-border-radius:10px">
  <center>
    <div style="font-size:30px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:20px; padding-top:8px">
    Average Damage Calculator
    </div>

    <div class=container>

      <h3>Calculate Target Average</h3>

      <table class=thisTable>
        <tr>
          <td>Type in your target average damage</td>
          <td><input type='number' id='a'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Type the amount of battles you want to achieve it by</td>
          <td><input type='number' id='b'/></td>
        <tr>
         <td>Type in your current number of battles</td>
         <td><input type='number' id='c'/></td>
        <tr>
          <td>Type in your current average damage</td>
          <td><input type='number' id='d'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="calculate-btn">calculate</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>  
            <span id="answer-cell"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

To round the answer you can use a number of methods, see below for some examples.

```js
var a = 24.5123678;

console.log(`Round up to nearest int: ${Math.ceil(a)}`);
console.log(`Round down to nearest int: ${Math.floor(a)}`);
console.log(`Round to the nearest int: ${Math.round(a)}`);
console.log(`Round up to a number of decimals: ${a.toFixed(4)}`);
```

Comment: you did it! you figured it out! thanks so much, I didn't know about that function. Is there any way to reduce the numbers in the answer? Right now I'm getting "2788.4560xxxxxxx" but just "2788" would be fine.

Comment: You could use `Math.ceil(ans)` to round up to the nearest integer or `Math.floor(ans)` to round down.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some examples of rounding numbers.

Comment: In the span? Would `math.ceil(ans) automatically remove decimals, or do I have to add a number after that?

Comment: I've add `Math.ceil` in the calculator so you know how to use it.

Comment: Okay thanks, that works quite well. I'm assuming what you've added is java script? Im a bit ahead of myself here but Im trying to learn a little bit

Comment: Yeah, I have added a bit of JavaScript. It is pretty much in line with what you had already written yourself. I do agree with @Snowmonkey about the naming of values. Make it descriptive, your future-self will thank you. `A`, `B`, `C`, and ,`D` may make sense now but it a few weeks it is a puzzle. I don't agree on the jQuery part. There is nothing you're doing that warrants including a library like jQuery.

Comment: I've updated the answer so it is inline with @Snowmonkey's answer only without using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged the question jQuery, I remade your example to utilise it. Also, there are a few suggested changes: field names/variable names would benefit from being clues to what they contain, and rather than hard-coding the event listeners, attach them programmatically. The comments in my code should show what's happening.

```js
// Rather than an inline click event listener, as the OP has 
//  tagged the question jQuery, we can simply attach the event
//  listener here.
$(".calc-btn").on("click", calculate);

/*****
 * function to actually calculate the target value. This gathers
 *   all the given fields, performs the requisite math, and outputs
 *   a rounded value to the answer pane.
 *****/
function calculate() {
  // Note the meaningful names. While not a key part of your
  //   question, it will help down the line with debugging errors
  //   if your variables and fields have meaningful names.
  var targetDamage = parseInt($("[name='target-damage']").val());
  var targetBattles = parseInt($("[name='target-battles']").val());
  var currentBattles = parseInt($("[name='current-battles']").val());
  var currentDamage = parseInt($("[name='current-damage']").val());

  // Given the above fields, we can see what we're actually doing
  //   rather than simply manipulating A, B, C and D.
  var ans = ((targetDamage * targetBattles) - (currentBattles * currentDamage)) / (targetBattles - currentBattles);
  var remainingBattles = targetBattles-currentBattles;


  // Stick the answer in the answer pane!
  $(".calculator-answer-pane").text("You need to average "+Math.round(ans)+" over the next "+remainingBattles+" battles to reach your target.");
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #05537b;
}

.thisTable td {
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.main-container {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

.calculator-container {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.calculator-main-pane {
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left
}

.box {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
}

.button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  width: 25px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.answer {
  padding-left: 10px
}

.answer b {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.how {
  color: #555;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 2px 4px
}

.how b {
  color: #D00;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <center>
    <div class="calculator-container">Average Damage Calculator</div>
    <div class="calculator-main-pane">
      <h3>Calculate Target Average</h3>
      <table class=thisTable>
        <tr>
          <td>Type in your target average damage</td>
          <td>
            <input type='number' name='target-damage' />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Type the amount of battles you want to achieve it by</td>
          <td>
            <input type='number' name='target-battles' />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Type in your current number of battles</td>
          <td>
            <input type='number' name='current-battles' />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Type in your current average damage</td>
          <td>
            <input type='number' name='current-damage' />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button class="calc-btn">calculate</button>
          </td>
          <td class="calculator-answer-pane"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Above and beyond work. But 2 questions. 1) How did you make it so that the boxes and the answer are alligned and centered? 2) Would it be possible to have the answer be something like this: "You need to average(2778) damage over the next(239) battles to reach your target damage.

I got the 239 from 500-261 because, that is how many more battles you need to play. Would that be possible to add since you added the meaninful names?

Comment: You were adding everything in a single table cell -- I simply put the label in one and the field in a second. And I've updated the text being placed in the answer pane, see the above. You can make the text pretty much whatever you might want.

Comment: Okay, I see how you did that, that's so super cool! the new labelling definitely made it easier, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new `td` to your table, and then use the `innerHTML` to add the result of your calculation to the new `td` (with `id="result"`) .

```js
function calculate() {
  var A = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var B = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var C = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var D = document.getElementById("d").value;

  var ans = ((A * B) - (C * D)) / (B - C);

  //Here you assign your result to the new td
  var Result = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + ans;
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #05537b;
}

.thisTable td {
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left
}

.box {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
}

.button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  width: 25px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.answer {
  padding-left: 10px
}

.answer b {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.how {
  color: #555;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 2px 4px
}

.how b {
  color: #D00;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div style="width:1000px; background-color:#FFF; padding:10px 20px; text-align:center; -moz-border-radius:10px">
    <div style="font-size:30px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:20px; padding-top:8px">Average Damage Calculator</div>
    <div class=container>
      <h3>Calculate Target Average</h3>
      <table class=thisTable>
        <tr>
          <td>Type in your target average damage <input type='number' id='a' /> </td> <td id="result">here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Type the amount of battles you want to achieve it by <input type='number' id='b' /></td>
          <tr>
            <td>Type in your current number of battles <input type='number' id='c' /></td>
            <tr>
              <td>Type in your current average damage <input type='number' id='d' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <button onClick='calculate()'>calculate</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```